# After connecting to VPN client can't browse any site but can chat & call on Skype

Tags: windows, windows-7, vpn

My problem is that I am able to chat, call and screen-share via skype but not able to browse any site when connected through my Windows VPN (say, VPN-W).

For `https` sites it gives `SSL Connection Error` and for `http` it gives `web-page not found` in Chrome browser.

**My VPN-W was working nicely till last week.**

I suppose since we had installed a few softwares like Sonic Wall Global VPN client, VMware client 5.5, handbrake DVD ripper, Mediacoder and VLC 64-bit, that might have caused the problem (it seems unlikely but still). So I

1. uninstalled all of these softwares
2. restarted PC after each uninstall
3. Ran CCleaner
4. deleted my VPN-W from `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`
5. reconfigured VPN-W.

But all this didn't work.

I thought may be there are some rules which might have been set-up on the VPN so I asked my colleagues to connect through my credentials and they were all able to do that without any issues. And all of them have all the softwares which I have installed except `Sonic Wall Global VPN client`.

So in conclusion it is my system which is behaving weirdly. I am not able to figure out exactly what is wrong with my system.

---

Here is how I configured my VPN:

1. Click on network icon in taskbar
2. Click on <kbd>Open Network and Sharing Center</kbd>.
3. Click on the <kbd>Setup a new connection or network</kbd> link in Change your Network Settings on the center of the window.
4. In the window that pops up, click <kbd>Connect to a workplace</kbd>, then click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
5. Select the <kbd>Use my Internet connection (VPN)</kbd> option.
6. In the window that appears, type the `Internet Address` and `Destination Name`, then click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
7. In the next window that comes enter `Username` and `Password` and click <kbd>Connect</kbd>.

Any pointers will help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked for faulty proxy settings on your system? How to: http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=5452

Answer (score 1):

With a VPN the first things I think about are routing issues related to the creation of the the new "virtual" network interface (*i.e*. default route, netmask, NAT) - these are usually dealt with automatically. A related issue is DNS lookup. Can you still access your nameserver? Are you able to use Google's public nameserver as a substitute? (`8.8.8.8`)

I think you have the key to your answer in something you said: "all of [my colleagues] have the softwares (sic) which I have installed except `Sonic Wall Global VPN client`".  It certainly sounds like a firewall issue - since Skype is able to find its way through firewalls you are able to continue using it; whereas client software expecting to be able to access a port in a "normal" fashion in order connect to external services are blocked by the firewall. Have you checked your firewall settings to be sure they are properly handling the VPN connection?

Comment: I have uninstalled `Sonic Wall Global VPN client` and have tried with disabling my firewall as well. May be I will check once again to be sure. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure but it seemed like `Sonic Wall Global VPN Client` did something with the drivers and hence I was not able to VPN. I also checked some other Windows VPN connections through my PC and they were also not working. Cisco VPN on the other hand was working.

---

So we took the last drastic step of formatting the `C Drive` and reinstalling windows, since we could not waste more time in this.

**And yes the VPN is working now.**

---

<sub>**Note:** If anybody has any idea about what drivers might have been affecte, I would test that and may accept that as an answer</sub>